# start position of table view is wrong in simulator, and is not the same in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I created a tableview in storyboard, which looks good, but the start position is wrong in the simulator or device. The 'Label' should not be at the same position as the time. How could I solve it??

[image: storyboard]

[image]

[image: in simulator]

Comment: in iOS 7, the status bar is included in View Controller. Do you want to keep the Status Bar or not ?

Comment: `Simulated metrics` are just that.  Simulated.  They're useful to set to how the view will actually display in order to help set up the look in the storyboard, but whether or not a navbar or tabbar shows up in the actual program is irrelevant to whether or not you've selected it as a simulated metric on the storyboard.

Comment: That is not tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulated metrics are just that. Simulated. They're useful to set to how the view will actually display in order to help set up the look in the storyboard, but whether or not a navbar or tabbar shows up in the actual program is irrelevant to whether or not you've selected it as a simulated metric on the storyboard.

In this case, you're probably using constraints, and setting the label's y origin to be 0 pixels below the container view.  When you use the simulated storyboard metrics, this puts the label just below the navbar that you're simulating on the storyboard.  But in your actual project, you've done nothing to include a navbar on this scene, and your label is appearing at the top of the view controller.

You can either learn how to prevent the status bar from displaying... or you can move the label's y origin to being a 20 pixels down (the height of the status bar).

---

I can provide more help if you provide more details on how you're doing your layout (autolayout?), and exactly how you want it to look.  But I'd start by leaving ALL of the simulated metrics on `inferred` and only ever explicitly change a simulated metric after you've written the code to programmatically add/remove one of the features you can change via the simulated metrics.

---

**If you take nothing else away from this answer, please understand this: Selecting an item from a simulated metrics dropdown menu only changes how the view appears in the storyboard and doesn't change what will actually display in your app.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I misunderstood the simulated metrics. My table view contains 1 static cell. There is one label at the top of the cell. What I want to do is to make cell be below the status bar.

Comment: I used autolayout and didn't added contraints.

Comment: Do you want a navigation bar or not?  Are you using auto-layout with constraints, or are you using constant x,y,width,height?

Comment: I don't want a navigation bar, but I want a status bar. I set the height of my cell by dragging its border down. Should I need to code to get the status bar?

Comment: The status bar will be there by default.  You should change the navbar simulated metric to inferred.  Now drag the label to the exact position you want it (there's a layout guide at y=20, right below the status bar).  Launch in the simulator and see how it looks.  If it's still not right, you'll need to set constraints probably: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Oh, sorry. I said something wrong. The status bar is there, but I want to let the cell be below it. I am surveying the doc you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

hope this will help you.