# How can I set all viewcontroller as a landscape in storyboard XCode6 (Swift)

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

My iPad application is fixed on landscape, and can't be changed during the whole lifetime.

I setup the project as:

[image: project setup]

and then in storyboard, I set the orientation as the landscape, but I don't know why the view does not change to landscape?

[image: storyboard setup]

Note: I am using Swift, XCode6.3.2, iOS8.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [start position of table view is wrong in simulator, and is not the same in storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415272/start-position-of-table-view-is-wrong-in-simulator-and-is-not-the-same-in-story)

Comment: Simulated metrics are just that, simulated.  Besides, the default size for the view controllers in the storyboard is a 600x600 square... you wouldn't notice if it were landscape or portrait when it's a square...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In the any | component  click on it and mouse over you can see the bottom text said the size of view for iPhone and iPad like following images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

if your application size class desable then that show direct reflaction like old way. but when your app size class enable that need to use with `wAny hComponet`

if size class enable  with landscape:

[image]

Same if size class disable with landscape:

[image]

If you want to use size class then you need to check viewcontroller preview like following step:

- Select view controller and then click on show the assistant editore.

[image]

- Then you have two part on your xcode like following:

[image]

- select a preview from following dropdown screenshot:

[image]

[image]

- after select prview you can see the right side one view that is the preview of your viewcontroller view's you can change it landscape or portrait by following.

[image]

- you can also check with all size by create new preview view by following.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, disabling the "Size Classes" works for me. I don't need adaptive UI. I only need for landscape iPad orientation.

Answer (score 1):

In simulated metrics, you've got the size selected as `Inferred`. If you want to see what it looks like on a specific device type, select that from the first drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard, the scene is universal so that you can use auto layout to adapt for various devices and orientations.

You can select iPad specifically from the simulated metrics:

[image: Simulated metrics]

Or you can, modify universal storyboard layout from the bottom panel.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for Xcode 8 - 
Click the View as: text at the bottom of the storyboard.

[image: Rotate to landscape]